# How to get screen dimensions using Qt?

Tags: qt, graphics

I need to obtain screen dimensions using Qt. I would think I'd use the Qt mobility apis here:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0-tp/

But I see nothing that would obtain screen size (x/y). Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: The current version of Qt mobility is 1.1.3, so you should use http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.1.3/  (but you do not need it here)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe the [QDesktopWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html) has what you need?

> const QRect QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry ( int screen = -1 ) const 
>   Returns the geometry of the screen with index screen. The default screen is used if screen is -1.
>   See also screenNumber().