# Qt: Set size of QMainWindow

Tags: qt, size, qmainwindow

I'm new to Qt, so I wonder whether there is a way to set the size of a `QMainWindow` to (for example) 70% of the user's desktop.
I tried the stretch factor but it didn't work. `QWidget::setFixedSize` worked but only with a pixel number, I think.

Comment: See this link:
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496327/how-to-get-screen-dimensions-using-qt>

And the you can calculate 70% of that.

Comment: amir go ahead and post as an answer.

Comment: kay it worked i edited my question with my code ;)

Comment: @dado2: Could you write an answer to your own question instead of modifying your question ? This would respect the Q/A style that StackOverflow encourage.

Comment: I have edited the question to improve grammar and formatting. Also I have added the solution as an answer to this question. If there's any problem with this - please comment - so that I can remove my answer and let @dadod2 or Amir eas write his answer here.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Thanks to Amir eas. The problem is solved. Here's the code for it:

```
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
...
QDesktopWidget dw;
MainWindow w;
...
int x=dw.width()*0.7;
int y=dw.height()*0.7;
w.setFixedSize(x,y);
```

Comment: This will not work so good for multi monitor setup :\ Any ideas for that?

Comment: @Wilhelmsen : you can use `QDesktiopWidget::primaryScreen()` like in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893328/qt-getting-the-screen-resolution-without-the-extended-monitor

Comment: Beware that as a side effect, the user won't be able to resize the window at all with this method. See the answer below for a better approach.

Answer (score 51):

Somewhere in your QMainWindow constructor, do this:

`resize(QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry(this).size() * 0.7);`

This will resize the window to 70% of the available screen space.

Comment: This should be the right answer, thanks! Still I wonder why this needs to be so cryptic in QT instead of simply being able to do something like `resize(640, 480)`.

Comment: @Timo: You can also do that, of course. But the idea is to adjust the window's size automatically in relation to the available screen resolution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `availableGeometry(QWidget*)` method in `QDesktopWidget`, this will give you the geometry of the screen that this widget is currently on. 
For example:

```
QRect screenSize = desktop.availableGeometry(this);
this->setFixedSize(QSize(screenSize.width * 0.7f, screenSize.height * 0.7f));
```

Where `this` is the MainWindow pointer.
This will work when using multiple screens.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update @muesli's answer for Qt6, `QDesktopWidget` had been deprecated in Qt5 and in Qt6 is removed.

The new equivalent code is

```
resize(QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->availableGeometry().size() * 0.7);
```