# QT getting the screen resolution without the extended monitor

Tags: qt

```
QDesktopWidget desktop;

int desktopHeight=desktop.geometry().height();
int desktopWidth=desktop.geometry().width();
this->resize(desktopWidth,desktopHeight);
```

for example my  main monitor  resolution is 1024 x 768 and my extended monitor resolution is 800x600.
the value i get from desktop height and width is the sum of the two monitor resolution. i only need to get the main monitor resolution. can somebody tell me how? thanks. I'm using qt 4.7.3

edit: I'm using dual screen, particularly in cashier ordering the main monitor is seen by the cashier and the extended are seen by the costumer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You pretty much had it, just give the screen ID of your main monitor to the `geometry()` call.

```
QDesktopWidget widget;
QRect mainScreenSize = widget.availableGeometry(widget.primaryScreen()); // or screenGeometry(), depending on your needs
```

Comment: so i can call the height by mainScreenSize->height() and width by mainScreenSize->width() ?

Comment: lastly on your comment you are talking about changing the availablegeometry to screengeometry depending on my needs?

Comment: availableGeometry() will exclude the space taken up by things like the taskbar

Comment: tested on a macbook pro, not accuate.