# resizing window in qt without using standard layouts

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtwidgets, qlayout

I’m using QT Creator and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to enable resizing when running the widget. I know when you apply a layout (horizontal, vertical, and grid) it enables resizing, but when I use these standard layouts they reconfigure all of the widgets I have put in the window. I’m trying to enable resizing but have all of the widgets I put in the window where I want them to be.

Comment: maybe this could help since you dont want to use standard layouts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893328/qt-getting-the-screen-resolution-without-the-extended-monitor

Answer (score 1):

Check the different layout behaviours. Use the horizontal and vertical 'spring' widget to make the other widgets to stay where they are. Use nested layouts when you want to combine the view of the widgets.

Comment: I have been using nested layouts. I think you're talking about the spacers. I have been trying to make use of those but they are not allowing me to change the size when I chose a layout.

Comment: Changing the size is a tricky thing. If you want to set the widget to a specified size, modify both the minimum and maximum size to the same value. Or set the sizePolicy to Fixed.

Comment: I'm not tryin to set it to a fixed size. My goal is to be able to adjust it as I adjust window.