Prevent QWindow from maximizing to full screen size
My application has a rendering window, and next to it, a command widget (with a smaller size). When the user clicks on the maximize icon of the rendering window, it should not maximize to the full screen size, but only to the full screen size minus the width of the command widget.
Limiting the screen size with setMaximumWidth does not work properly when the user hits the Maximize Icon. It still expands to full screen. Whereas, resizing the window when dragging the frame works as expected (size cannot be exceeded beyond maximumWidth, which is max screen width minus widget width).
Is there a way to intercept the maximize event or to limit the max size and get it recognized when the user hits the maximize icon?
And it would be nice if I could keep the Maximize Icon of the window available, visible and working.

Maybe you can react on the resize event of your main window, and set the preferred size with something like mainWindow.resize(maxSize);. I think this might be helpful then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280323/qt-set-size-of-qmainwindow

Reacting on the resize event unfortunately don't help, because any change to the size of the window launched from the resize event is firing the signal again. Which then leads to heavy workarounds (store and restore some global sizing variables, etc.) which I would like to avoid to keep the code clean.

You may want to either disable the maximize function entirely, or intercept it and do a resize instead.

can you do a window within a window, and set the maximum size on the inner window? You should be able to make the outer window invisible.

Intercepting the window state change will only work partially: you could override changeEvent() to capture WindowStateChange events (checking if windowState() == WindowMaximized) and eventually resize again, but then the window won't be in maximized state anymore; the title bar will still show the "maximize" button, and restoring to the previous size won't be possible anymore; not very UX friendly. The only viable option I can think of is to completely prevent maximizing from the OS (with setWindowFlags()), and add a button somewhere to allow the "pseudo-maximize" (and restore).

Alternatively, if that's a viable option (you didn't explain what that "rendering window" actually is), intercept window state changes as above, and embed the command widget in it when maximized, otherwise restore it as a separate window. Yet, if you're on Linux (X11 at least, don't know about Wayland), you may never get a state change event when the window is normalized by the user, so the above solution will never work appropriately as Qt has no way to know when/if a previously maximized window is restored (see the notes about maximized.

Thank you for the comments. It sounds like there is no easy way and I fear I need a "dirty" workaround. Overriding the changeEvent is one thing I will try, but I guess it shows similar behavior like intercepting from the resizeEvent (which I have implemented), simply because the signal is fired again. - Yes, I am on Linux and the rendering window is an OpenGL Window.
